# Unity Steamworks-Leaderboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, steam

I have created an ingame scoreboard, where i want you to be able to see the players who are connected to the server Steam username. So far i've created the scoreboard and everything, the only thing now is getting the steam username to show instead of my "player name goes here" text. I've tried several things but with no success :(

This is the Scoreboard Script:

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject playerScoreboardItem;

[SerializeField]
Transform playerScoreboardList;

void OnEnable()
{
    Player[] players = GameManager.GetAllPlayers();

    foreach(Player player in players)
    {
        GameObject itemGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(playerScoreboardItem, playerScoreboardList);
        PlayerScoreboardItem item = GetComponent<PlayerScoreboardItem>();
        if(item != null)
        {
            item.Setup(SteamFriends.GetPersonaName());
        }
    }
}

void OnDisable()
{
    foreach(Transform child in playerScoreboardList)
    {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

And this is the ScoreboardItem Script:

```
    [SerializeField]
Text usernameText;

public void Setup(string username)
{
    usernameText.text = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();
}
```

}

And the last script:

```
            string username = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();

        CmdSetUsername(transform.name, username);
    }

    GetComponent<Player>().Setup();
}

[Command]
void CmdSetUsername (string playerID, string username)
{
    Player player = GameManager.GetPlayer(playerID);
    if(player == null)
    {
        Debug.Log(SteamFriends.GetPersonaName() + "joined!");
        player.username = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eeer, please note that you can edit your questions when you have more information to supply, rather than asking it repeatedly. Additionally, you don't need to wait for others to close your questions - you can delete them yourself if you feel they are no longer relevant for the site (provided they don't have upvoted answers).

Comment: sorry, didnt find anywhere to delete it ;(

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you would need to integrate steamworks to your game.
This api will help you retrieve users, achievements, steamworkshop etc. on your game.

To make steamworks work in your game you need to get approved by valve to have your game on steam, for example have it greenlit.

Here is a tutorial with all the information regarding steamworks on Unity3D: [Tutorial](http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/integrating-unity-game-steamworks/).

How do I loop through the list of friends and get their name and status?

Hope this will help you understand more about this subject.

**EDIT:**
I found some documentation and it is actually really easy.

Go to [this](http://steamworks.github.io/snippits/#steamfriends) website for more documentation.

**EDIT2:**
Ok so no friends, Sorry for that.

I think you actually have to handle this yourself.
Everytime a user connects to the game server add them to a list so you can get them easily.
Then just use that list to handle the scoreboard.

- Mennolp

Comment: I have steamworks implemented, i just want to know how to get all the other players username and shown on an UI Text :)

Comment: Oh I see, really didn't get that from the question you asked above.
I'd suggest looking at UI Canvas, usage of prefabs and vertical layout component.

Comment: yeah, i've created a Text variable, the only thing i need is the code that gives you players steamid/steam name

Comment: Then what does this function do? **SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();**

Comment: @Avi3ator I just edited my answer, when you have time look at it.

Comment: I dont want to get my friends name, i want to get all the players connected steam names

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I suddenly thought about friends because of the SteamFriends class, my mistake.

Comment: np :P but do you know if its possible to get steam names from connected clients? :)